# What hapenned to the Mexican officer who was found with James Fannin's watch in the Battle of San Jacinto of the Texas Revolution?

Tags: texas

I read an article in the [New Georgia Encyclopedia on James Walker Fannin Jr.](https://www.georgiaencyclopedia.org/articles/government-politics/james-walker-fannin-jr-1804-1836/) which says:

> The [Texan] officials who found [James Fannin's watch in the possession of a Mexican officer] assumed the Mexican was responsible for Fannin’s murder; he thus met death in a like manner as Fannin [shot in the head].

However, I this is the only source I have found mentioning this. I asked for one in a support ticket, but have not received a response.

Comment: Gary Brown,"Hesitant Martyr of the Texas Revolution: James Walker Fannin." Taylor Trade Publications, 2000, [p. 258](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hesitant_Martyr_of_the_Texas_Revolution/HU33lgrOCiEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA258)
'The Dallas Historical Society now exhibits the watch and claims that the officer who ordered Fannin's execution was captured with the watch after the battle of Jacinto and promptly chastised in the same manner as he had killed Fannin. No reports of the aftermath of San Jacinto, however, verify the collection of the watch -- an event that should have been prominent..

Comment: Brown apparently found no corroborating evidence for this story and seems doubtful of the claim, as it should have featured prominently in contemporary reports if true. So it seems likely that the story is apocryphal.

Comment: José Enrique de la Peña, "Le rebelión de Texas", unpublished manuscript, 1836, identifies the officer leading Fannin's execution (and who presumably pocketed the watch) as Carolino Huerta, belonging to a unit called Tres Villas.

Comment: @njuffa seems to be treating this matter with the proper amount of detachment. I should warn folks looking into this that most of your sources are going to be from the victors, and I've in the past found Texan sources wrt conflicts with Mexico in particular ... er ... charmingly one-sided.

Comment: For instance, there's a really pretty monument near La Grange Texas commemorating the [Mier Expedition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mier_expedition), which was a group of Texan privateers (state-sponsored bandits) who got caught in Mexico by the army and shot. The original plaque was labeled "Shrine to the Texas Martyrs".

Comment: The 1836 manuscript of [José Enrique de la Peña](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Enrique_de_la_Pe%C3%B1a), a Mexican source (published in 1955), confirms that Fannin handed over his watch: "[...] commandante del punto, para depositar con el su reloj, para que le hiciera el favor de remitirlo a su esposa, como la ultima prenda de su ternura, con la carta que le habia escrito; pero el capitan de Tres Villas, don Carolino Huerta, que iba a mandar la ejecucion, tuvo la crueldad de negarle esta pequeña gracia [...]". I cannot find anything on captain Huerta's life after the Fannin execution

Comment: I noticed belatedly that the authenticity of de la Peña's 1836 manuscript as published in 1955 is in doubt. Per the Wikipedia article I linked above: "Historians disagree on whether any or all of the book had been faked."

Comment: I don't have specific information on this artifact or this story -- hence a comment about directions for further research, not an answer -- but if you're trying to trace sources here, and the story comes at least in part from the Dallas Historical Society, you might start out looking for accounts in the Quarterly of the Texas State Historical Association ([available free via JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/journal/quartxstahista)); [Portal to Texas Early Texas Newspapers](https://texashistory.unt.edu/explore/collections/ETXNP/) might also be a good place to look.

Comment: I mention these sources because, *in general*, a lot of this kind of Texiana artifacts and anecdotes tend to bottom out in collections and historical reminiscences appearing in the 1870s-1900s. A lot of TSHA's early activity was to publish reminiscences (true, false, partial, or dubious; lots was accepted very uncritically) of Texian veterans in their old age, or collect artifacts donated by their families, as they realized the generation of the 1830s was aging and dying off. Or it is possible that DHS got the watch later, and the story directly from the family at the time of the donation.